# How to prove $ \mathit {X}$ is path connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

${\mathbb{R}}^{2} $ **Euclidean 2-space**,Let $\mathit {X} \subset  \mathbb{R}^{2} $.$$\mathit {X}=[-2,2]\times[-1,0]\cup[-2,-1]\times[0,1]\cup[1,2]\times[0,1]$$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$                   [image]

From the geometric intuition, we know $ \mathit {X}$  is ***path connected***. I want to prove it  theoretically.So I tied to use **Definition**: ***A  topological space $\mathit {X} $ is path connected if  for every $x,y\in \mathit {X}$ there is a path in $\mathit {X}$ from $x$ to $y$***.but for every $x,y\in \mathit{X}$, finding a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathit{X}$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$  is  seemingly difficulty.
I need some help to go further or  some other solutions to prove it. Any of your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

*Hint* You can partition your set into three overlapping convex (and hence path connected) subsets, namely three rectangles. Then use that if $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are path connected and $A_i\cap A_{i+1}$ is nonempty path-connected for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$ then their union is path connected.

Comment: I didn't know the nice property you have given .Indeed,using this conlustion, it will be easily proved ! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

For any $A(x_1,y_1), B(x_2,y_2) \in X$ there is a path $ACDB$, where $C(x_1;-\frac{1}{2})$ and $D(x_2,-\frac{1}{2})$.

You can try to construct a function $f$ consisting of three parts $f_1:[0,\frac{1}{3}] \to AC$, $f_2:[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}] \to CD$ and $f_3:[\frac{2}{3},1] \to DB$ (here $f_1(\frac{1}{3})$ should be equal to $f_2(\frac{1}{3})$ and similarly for $f_2$ and $f_3$ in $\frac{2}{3}$).